# Python: Dealing with mess txt file

Tags: python

I have a txt file like below structure:

```
Product: 1010
Account    Amount    Date
123                      50$          2019-12-29
Product: 1020
Account    Amount    Date
124                      100$          2019-12-30*
```

And I'm new to python esp pandas, so I wonder if I could use python to structure the output like:

```
Product,Account,Amount,Date
1010,123,50%,2019-12-29
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution with regular expressions. This assumes that every entry has 4 fields and that the first one is delimited by a colon:

```py
import re
import pandas as pd

content = '''
Product: 1010
Account    Amount    Date
123                      50$          2019-12-29
Product: 1020
Account    Amount    Date
124                      100$          2019-12-30*
'''

pattern = re.compile(r'(\S+):\s*(\S+)\n(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\n(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)')
df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(zip([k]+kv[:3], [v]+kv[3:]))
    for k, v, *kv in pattern.findall(content)
])
```

```py
>>> df
  Product Account Amount         Date
0    1010     123    50$   2019-12-29
1    1020     124   100$  2019-12-30*
```

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not a regular format, you should be able to read your file line by line, expecting the following format:

```
Product: (\d+)
```

If and only if you have a match, then the next line must match this format:

```
Account    Amount    Date
```

And then you just need to parse a line of this format:

```
^(\d+)\s+(\d+\$)\s+(\d+-\d+-\d+)$
```

Repeat for however long the file is, and from that, you should be able to convert your TXT file to a CSV and load it with the `csv` module.

Use regular expressions from the `re` module to validate the format and extract the values.

Comment: If you are dealing with extremely large files, you can avoid using an intermediate CSV file if you use StringIO. It's like a file object that is entirely in memory, so your script would append a CSV-formatted line to it and the CSV reader module would read from it.

Comment: thanks for the feedback!! very helpful! however as I'm new to Python, could you provide some sample codes? Thanks!

Comment: Although I appreciate your enthusiasm, you're not asking for help, you're asking for someone to write the code for you. StackOverflow is not the place for this.

Comment: you read through me,:) thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

My assumptions: you know the file structure in advance and **IT IS FIXED** and you have tabs (\t) as a separators

```
import pandas as pd
product_columns = ['Product','Account','Amount','Date']
product_data_list = []
fp = open('./data.txt', 'r');
line = fp.readline().strip()
product_id = None

while line:
    if line.find('Product:') == 0:
        product_id = line[9:]
    elif line.find('Account') == -1:
        record_data = line.split('\t')
        account = record_data[0]
        amount = record_data[1]
        date = record_data[2]
        record = {
                        'Product': product_id,
                        'Account': account,
                        'Amount': amount,
                        'Date': date
                        }

        product_data_list.append(record)

    line = fp.readline().strip()

fp.close()
product_data = pd.DataFrame.from_records(product_data_list)
print(product_data)
```

Comment: hmm I tried this but got this output :Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []

Comment: Check your file format. Whether you have key word "Product:" and tabs (\t) there.

Comment: I could post my file but not sure how to do that, seems the code issue is it has no loop at all

Comment: "while line:" - this is the loop

Answer (score 0):

If your file is not formatted neatly for tabular data, you can try this sample below:

```
import pandas as pd

file = '''
  Product: 1010
  Account    Amount    Date
  123                      50$          2019-12-29
  Product: 1020
  Account    Amount    Date
  124                      100$          2019-12-30*
'''

l = []
place = 0

for i, line in enumerate(file.split()):
  i+1
  if i % 8 == 1:
    l.append([line])
  elif i % 8 == 5 or i % 8 == 6 or i % 8 == 7:
    l[place].append(line)
  if i % 8 == 7:
    place += 1

columns = ['Product', 'Account', 'Amount', 'Date']

df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=columns)
print(df)

>>>
 Product Account Amount         Date
0    1010     123    50$   2019-12-29
1    1020     124   100$  2019-12-30*
```

This will get the job done if there are no null values. Using regex might be cleaner too.